# RichTextBox to Array

Tags: c#

So I'm a complete noob when it comes to programming but unfortunately for me I got stuck with this project for work.  Here's the situation:  A user pastes a series of hostnames into a rich text box.  The program adds each line to an array.  Here's the code:

```
TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(hostNames.Text);
string rawServerNameInput = hostNames.Text;
int itemCount = hostNames.Lines.Length;
string[] serverNames = new string[itemCount];

int rows;

//string[] serverNames = new string[rows];
int entries = serverNames.Length;
Console.Write(serverNames);
for (int r = 0; r < itemCount; r++)
{
    serverNames[r] = read.ReadLine();
}
//MessageBox.Show(serverNames[1]);
foreach (string s in serverNames)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

I haven't quite got to the point of adding to the array yet since I'm still Googling that information.  I haven't had much luck with it so any help would be great.  The array itself is set to the number of lines entered in the box.

Comment: What is it exactly you are having trouble doing?

Comment: Right now it's actually breaking down the user input by lines.  For example: Server1, Server2, etc should each be added individually to the array. so Server1 would be Array[0], Server2 = Array[1] etc.

Comment: And what would you like to have happen?

Comment: I'm going to append each hostname to the end of a URL and retrive data from the url.

Comment: the hostNames.Line.Length is counting how many hostnames are in the textbox the setting the array to this number.  That seems to be working OK it's just adding each line individually to the array that seems to be giving me the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` has a `Lines` property that is a `string[]` array  ... already there for you.

So all you need is:

```
var lines = hostNames.Lines;
```

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: `TextBox` in newer versions of .NET also inherits from `TextBoxBase` .. which is where the `Lines` property comes from.

Comment: humm...textbox.Lines also.